# Transaction on defriend and multi databases

Tags: sql-server, mysql, mongodb, transaction

I have a big issue when i'm working with multi database and diffrent databases as same time.

The problem is that I'm working with mssql, mysql and mongodb at sametime, and what I need is a way to be sure whats in "mysql" its there when I hit mongodb and, if something failed in eg. mssql, then rollback all modifications.

I know I can code so I check with a select before everything every time, but if my rollback in this case get disconnected how can I be sure on my rollback is success?

Is there a nice way to handle this issue, or its just brian-hedick to work with multi database connections and transactions?

Comment: Is your question how to perform an atomic distributed transaction? You either need 2-phase commits and a coordinator or an asynchronous pattern like [saga](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html).

Comment: [XA Transactions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/xa-statements.html)